# How to get the parent of an element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have multiple tables on a website, I need to find the table with element that has text 'blabla' and then in that same table I will press a button, I tried this:

```
a = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[contains(text(),"blabla")]')
b = a.find_element_by_xpath('..')
browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'{b}/btn').click()

b --> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0c5008a89c2da6d4b2e83f4237afc6ba", element="ef8fddcc-88fb-4947-b2c2-2e5ac400b5a1")>
```

but it gave me that this is an invalid xpath, as b is not the xpath but rather something else I don't understand, so does anyone have any idea how to do this correctly ? or if it is possible

EDIT:
this is an example for a table

```
<tr style="height:30px;">
            <td valign="top" style="width:50px;">
                            <b>Code:</b><br>
                            <a href="editcourse_lookup.aspx?coursecode=SB32173" target="_blank">
                                SB32173
                            </a>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1
                            <br>
                            
                            
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('learningplan_welcome.aspx?coursecode=SB32173&amp;teacherid=365&amp;studid=13150&amp;regNo=22478','windowname1','width=900, height=600');return false;" target="_blank">View Report</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('Convert-report.aspx?coursecode=SB32173&amp;teacherid=365&amp;studid=13150&amp;regNo=22478','windowname1','width=550, height=180');return false;" target="_blank">Convert Report</a>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblpuseddetails_0"></span>
                              <br>
                            
                                <br>
                             <a href="editsubs.aspx?mode=Modify&amp;courseCode=SB32173&amp;sid=13150&amp;uid=musafdar@uncg.edu&amp;g=All&amp;type=s&amp;parentpage=y" target="_blank">Edit</a>
                            <br>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblSubjectdetails_0" style="font-size:10px;"><b>Member Name:</b>Osman Khan<br><b>Subject:</b>Tajweed ul Quran Level 1<br><b>Curriculum:</b><br><b>Material:</b>Tajweed ul Quran Level 1</span>

                        </td><td align="center" style="width:130px;">
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            Wed, 04 Aug 2021
                            -
                            Wed, 29 Sep 2021
                            <br>
                            Wed, 1:00 AM - 2:00 AM<br>Fri, 1:00 AM - 2:00 AM<br>Sun, 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM
                            <br>
                            <a href="editCourse1To1.aspx?mode=Modify&amp;courseCode=SB32173" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_a_EditCourse_0" style="color: Blue;">Modify</a><br>
                            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_a_NewSubscr_0" style="color: Blue;cursor:pointer;" title="Book New Subscription" onclick="window.open('addcourse_1To1.aspx?reg=old&amp;mode=new&amp;catid=1&amp;coursecode=SB32173&amp;studentid=13148&amp;username=Irfan safdar&amp;timezone=13&amp;country=869&amp;sid=13150&amp;g=All&amp;type=s','windowname1','location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=900, height=650')">
                           Book New Subscription
                            </a>
                            <br><br>
                              <a onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure to Reschedule ?');" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkReschedule_0" title="Click to Reschedule" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkReschedule','')">Reschedule</a>
                            
                             
                              
                        </td><td align="center">
                         Fri, 1:00 AM - 2:00 AM<br>Sun, 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM<br>Wed, 1:00 AM - 2:00 AM<br>20<br>0.00<br><a href="popup/updatesubscriptionpackage.aspx?coursecode=SB32173&amp;sid=13150&amp;subsno=155534" target="_blank">Amend Default Subscription</a><br><br><a href="popup/Reschedule_Remaining_classes.aspx?coursecode=SB32173&amp;mode=CD" target="_blank">Amend Current Subscription</a>
                        
                       </td><td align="center">
                            
                            Mohamed Sawy
                            <br>
                            <a href="Send_Email.aspx?emailcode=Teacher_Confirm&amp;coursecode=SB32173&amp;back_sid=13150&amp;back_g=All&amp;back_type=s">
                                Confirm()</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="Send_Email.aspx?emailcode=Teacher_Cancel&amp;coursecode=SB32173&amp;back_sid=13150&amp;back_g=All&amp;back_type=s">
                                Cancel()</a>
                                
                                <br><a target="_blank" href="PopUp/createmessage.aspx?mode=Teacher&amp;tid=365"><img src="images/email.jpg" width="25" height="19"></a><a target="_blank" href="PopUp/SMSText.aspx?mode=Teacher&amp;tid=365"><img src="images/text.jpeg" width="22" height="20"></a><a target="_blank" href="PopUp/call.aspx?mode=Teacher&amp;tid=365" '=""><img src="images/iphone-call-icon.jpg" width="22" height="20"></a><a target="_blank" title="Student Notes" href="PopUp/teachernotes.aspx?tid=365" '=""><img src="images/notes.jpeg" width="22" height="20"></a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="popup/Update_Teacher.aspx?coursecode=SB32173" target="_blank">Change Teacher</a>
                                 <br><br><a href="https://secure.examhelper.org/eaalim/teacher/calendar/default.aspx?tid=365" target="_blank">View Teacher Calendar</a>
                        </td><td align="center" style="width:50px;">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblinvoiceno_0">22478</span><br>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblinvoicedate_0">Wed, 04 Aug 2021</span>
                        </td><td align="center" style="width:50px;">
                            <a href="SendInvoice_1To1.aspx?coursecode=SB32173&amp;back_sid=13150&amp;back_g=All&amp;back_type=s">
                                Invoice(0)</a>
                        </td><td align="center">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblNoOfLessons_0">20</span>
                        </td><td align="center" style="width:50px;">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblAttended_0">0</span>
                        </td><td align="center" style="width:50px;">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblAbsent_0">1</span>
                        </td><td align="center">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblMarkup_0">0 out of 5</span><br>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('edit-markup.aspx?coursecode=SB32173','windowname1','width=400, height=180');return false;" target="_blank">Modify</a>
                        </td><td align="center" style="width:50px;">
                            
                           
                            19
                            <hr>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblTotalLessonHtml_0" style="font-size:9px;"><b>Total Lessons:</b>20<br><b>Total Hrs:</b>20<br><b>Total Lessons Left:</b>19<br><b>Total Hrs Left:</b>5<br><b>Total Extra Lessons Left:</b>0<br><b>Total Extra Hrs Left:</b>0mins<br><b>Total Free Lessons Left:</b>0<br><b>Total Free Hrs Left:</b>0mins</span>
                              <hr>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblmissinglessons_0">20/20=0 missing</span>
                        </td><td align="right" style="width:50px;">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblcoursefee_0">0&nbsp;£</span>
                        </td><td align="center">
                            <a href="viewlessons.aspx?courseid=SB32173&amp;regno=22478&amp;cname=Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1" target="_blank">View</a><br><br><br>
                                 <a href="popup/addCourseLesson.aspx?id=SB32173" target="_blank">
                                Add Lessons
                            </a>
                        </td><td align="center">
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lblBooked_0">Enroled </span>
                        </td><td align="center">
                            <a onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure to change Live Chat Status ?');" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkLiveChatStatus_0" title="Click to Active/InActive" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkLiveChatStatus','')">Active</a>
                        </td><td align="center">
                            
                            Active

                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$ddlStatus" onchange="return ShowConfirm(this);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$ddlStatus\',\'\')', 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_ddlStatus_0" style="border-color:#999999;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Change Status</option>
                <option value="Active">Active</option>
                <option value="Archive">Archive</option>
                <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>

            </select>
                             <br> <br>
                                         <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$ddlAction" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$ddlAction\',\'\')', 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_ddlAction_0" style="border-color:#999999;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;width:170px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Pause Course - select</option>
                <option value="Pause Course">Pause Course with pending lessons</option>

            </select>

                        </td><td align="center">
                            
                        </td><td align="center">
                       
                        <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$drpwhiz" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_drpwhiz_0" style="border-color:#999999;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="999,zoomfree">Zoom Free</option>
                <option value="1,braincert">Braincert</option>
                <option value="1,wiziq">WizIQ 25</option>
                <option value="2,wiziq">WizIQ 100</option>
                <option value="3,wiziq">WizIQ 500</option>

            </select>
                                  <br>
                                   <a id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkswhiz_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkswhiz','')">Go</a>
                             <br>
                            <a onclick="alert('You have already generated the lesson url for this course.');" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkGenUrl1_0" title="Already Generated" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkGenUrl1','')">Generated</a>
                            
                            <hr>
                             <a onclick="return confirmGenUrl();" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_LinkButton1_0" title="Click to Generate url" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$LinkButton1','')">Re-Generate Existing URL</a>
                        </td><td align="center">
                              <a onclick="return confirm('Are sure want to request for ecertficate?');" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkRequestCertificate_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkRequestCertificate','')">Request eCertificate(0)</a>

                            <br>
                            <a href="Certificate-logs.aspx?coursecode=SB32173" target="_blank">Send Certificate</a>
                             <br>
                            <a onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure to Delete ?');" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkactive11_0" title="Click to Delete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkactive11','')">Delete</a>
                            <br>
                            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_lnkstatusActive_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$lnkstatusActive','')">Active SMS</a>
                              <br>
                             <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$ddlclasstype" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$gv_1To1CourseDetails$ctl02$ddlclasstype\',\'\')', 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder3_gv_1To1CourseDetails_ddlclasstype_0" style="border-color:#999999;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="Auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="Manual">Manual</option>

            </select>
                        </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: What URL are you running this on?

Comment: sorry, I can't give it to you

Comment: anyway, is there a way to locate a parent of a certain element and then in that parent you locate a button ?

Comment: That's okay. In that case, can you put the HTML of the table in the question? Feel free to anonymise any data in it.

Comment: I want to find the view btn, but there are multiple tables, so I search with a certain word like a code and then in the table that contain this code, I need to press on the view btn related to that table

Comment: </td><td align="center">
                            <a href="viewlessons.aspx?courseid=SB32173&amp;regno=22478&amp;cname=Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1" target="_blank">View</a>

Comment: I mean this one, this is not a button, sorry my mistake

Comment: All good - that makes sense. So what would be a specific example of the text you would like for? i.e. not "blabla"

Comment: let's say '22478'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer this part

> is there a way to locate a parent of a certain element and then in
> that parent you locate a button

Let's say this is the xpath :

```
//*[contains(text(),"blabla")]
```

you can use `/..` or `/parent::node-name` to reach to the parent node.

Let's understand from the example :-

```
//*[contains(text(),"blabla")]/..
```

should locate the Parent node, of `//*[contains(text(),"blabla")]`

also in case you want to have parent filter, you can equivalently use :-

```
 //*[contains(text(),"blabla")]/parent::div[@id='some id']
```

in this case it will look for parent `div` (this is just an example) who has `id` equals to `some id`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy of the HTML that you are looking for:

```html
<a href="viewlessons.aspx?courseid=SB32173&amp;regno=22478&amp;cname=Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1" target="_blank">View</a>
```

From reading the questions/comments, I see that the way to uniquely locate this is that it has `View` as the link text and contains `22478`.

For testing, let's make a bunch of similar links, which we want to avoid:

```html
<div><a href="viewlessons.aspx?courseid=1&amp;regno=4815162342&amp;cname=Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1" target="_blank">View</a></div>
<div><a href="viewlessons.aspx?courseid=2&amp;regno=22478&amp;cname=Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1" target="_blank">Discussion</a></div>
<div><a href="viewlessons.aspx?courseid=3&amp;regno=22478&amp;cname=Azan - Tajweed ul Quran Level 1" target="_blank">View</a></div>
```

- Link 1 has a different number.
- Link 2 has different link text.
- Link 3 is our intended link.

An XPATH to cover the first condition would be:

`//a[contains(@href,"22478")]`

That will find an `a` element with a `href` attribute that contains `22478`. That's a helpful start, but it will still match other unwanted links, such as link 2 in our example. So let's add the second condition:

`//a[contains(@href,"22478")][text()="View"]`

Now we check that the link text is `View`. This will only match the third link from our examples.

In code this would be:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"22478")][text()="View"]');
link.click();
```